# changing specific columns to that of values in the list in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Fairly new to coding and python.

My DataFrame looks like this at the moment.

```
Text          Location
....          NY, USA
....          NewYork
....          Austin,Texas
....          Tx
....          California
....          Somehere on Earth
```

The DataFrame consists of tweets and location extracted from the Users Bio.

```
states = ["AL","Alabama", "AK","Alaska", "AS", "American Samoa", "AZ", "Arizona",  "AR", "Arkansas", "CA", "California", "CO", "Colarado" "CT", "Connecticut"  "DE", "Delaware", "DC", "District Of Columbia", "FM", "Federated States Of Micronesia", "FL", "Florida" "GA", "Georgia", "GU", "Guam" "HI", "Hawaii", "ID", "Idaho", "IL", "Illinois", "IN", "Indiana","IA", "Iowa", "KS", "Kansas",  "KY", "Kentucky", "LA", "Louisiana","ME", "Maine", "MH", "Marshall Islands", "MD", "Maryland", "MA", "Massachusetts", "MI", "Michigan", "MN", "Minnesota", "MS", "Mississippi", "MO", "Missouri", "MT",  "Montana", "NE", "Nebraska", "NV", "Nevada", "NH", "New Hampshire", "NJ", "New Jersey", "NM", "New Mexico", "NY", "New York", "NC", "North Carolina", "ND", "North Dakota", "MP", "Northern Mariana Islands", "OH", "Ohio", "OK", "Oklahoma", "OR", "Oregon", "PW", "Palau", "PA", "Pennsylvania","PR", "Puerto Rico", "RI", "Rhode Island", "SC", "South Carolina", "SD", "South Dakota", "TN", "Tennessee", "TX", "Texas", "UT", "Utah", "VT", "Vermont", "VI", "Virgin Islands", "VA", "Virginia", "WA",  "Washington", "WV", "West Virginia", "WI", "Wisconsin", "WY", "Wyoming"]
```

Now Im trying to find out any if there is a way to change the location field to the following format.

```
Text         Location
....         NY
....         NewYork
....         Texas
....         Tx
....         California
....         NaN
```

I tried replacing values on the list. But it just doesn't do the job. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: i don't quite understand your desired data set - do you want to have full state names or their abbreviations?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. So basically I created this list of state names with abbreviations. So technically both would do. So in the second row of the location column, it says Austin, Texas. But I want only Texas (Which is one of the values in my list).

Comment: I'll ask you the same thing I asked yesterday: Whay have you done?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a lambda function with some regular expressions.

```
import re
states_lower = [state.lower() for state in states]
df['NewLocation'] = df['Location'].map(lambda x: ' '.join([loc for loc in re.findall('\\w+',x) if loc.lower() in states]))
```

- First, lowercase all your states for easier matching
- The regex grabs all the words
- Loop through the resulting list to determine which of those words are in the `states` list
- Join the rest of the items together so you end up with a string

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
In [230]: df
Out[230]:
   Text           Location
0  ....            NY, USA
1  ....            NewYork
2  ....       Austin,Texas
3  ....                 Tx
4  ....         California
5  ....  Somehere on Earth

In [231]: states = [
     ...:   "AL","Alabama", "AK","Alaska", "AS", "American Samoa", "AZ", "Arizona",  "AR", "Arkansas",
     ...:   "CA", "California", "CO", "Colarado", "CT", "Connecticut", "DE", "Delaware", "DC", "District Of Columbia",
     ...:   "FM", "Federated States Of Micronesia", "FL", "Florida", "GA", "Georgia", "GU", "Guam", "HI", "Hawaii",
     ...:   "ID", "Idaho", "IL", "Illinois", "IN", "Indiana","IA", "Iowa", "KS", "Kansas", "KY", "Kentucky",
     ...:   "LA", "Louisiana","ME", "Maine", "MH", "Marshall Islands", "MD", "Maryland", "MA", "Massachusetts",
     ...:   "MI", "Michigan", "MN", "Minnesota", "MS", "Mississippi", "MO", "Missouri", "MT",  "Montana",
     ...:   "NE", "Nebraska", "NV", "Nevada", "NH", "New Hampshire", "NJ", "New Jersey", "NM", "New Mexico",
     ...:   "NY", "New York", "NC", "North Carolina", "ND", "North Dakota", "MP", "Northern Mariana Islands",
     ...:   "OH", "Ohio", "OK", "Oklahoma", "OR", "Oregon", "PW", "Palau", "PA", "Pennsylvania","PR", "Puerto Rico",
     ...:   "RI", "Rhode Island", "SC", "South Carolina", "SD", "South Dakota", "TN", "Tennessee", "TX", "Texas",
     ...:   "UT", "Utah", "VT", "Vermont", "VI", "Virgin Islands", "VA", "Virginia", "WA",  "Washington",
     ...:   "WV", "West Virginia", "WI", "Wisconsin", "WY", "Wyoming"]
     ...:

In [232]: pat = [r'.*\b{}\b.*'.format(x.upper()) for x in states]
     ...: repl = [states[i//2*2] for i,_ in enumerate(states)]
     ...:

In [233]: df.Location.str.upper().replace(pat, repl, regex=True)
Out[233]:
0                   NY
1              NEWYORK
2                   TX
3                   TX
4                   CA
5    SOMEHERE ON EARTH
Name: Location, dtype: object
```